# Prove that $\frac{n^2+(-1)^nn+2}{7n^2+3}$ converges to $\frac{1}{7}$

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\frac{n^2+(-1)^nn+2}{7n^2+3}$ converges to $\frac{1}{7}$ using the definition of convergence.

Skratch work:

I need $\mid\frac{n^2+(-1)^nn+2}{7n^2+3}-\frac{1}{7}\mid<\epsilon$.

So I take $\frac{n^2+(-1)^nn+2}{7n^2+3}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{7(-1)^nn+11}{7(7n^2+3)}$.

For $n=1$, $\frac{7(-1)^nn+11}{7(7n^2+3)}=\frac{-4}{70}$

For $n=2$, $\frac{7(-1)^nn+11}{7(7n^2+3)}=\frac{24}{196}$

For $n=4$, $\frac{7(-1)^nn+11}{7(7n^2+3)}=\frac{39}{805}$.

So I think I can safely say that $\frac{7(-1)^nn+11}{7(7n^2+3)}<\frac{1}{n}$.

Now I can start the proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. And choose $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Hence, $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. So $n>N \implies \mid\frac{n^2+(-1)^nn+2}{7n^2+3}-\frac{1}{7}\mid < \frac{1}{n}< \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

Does this proof look correct? I think I may have made a mistake in choosing $N$. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thinking that you can safely say is not enough. You need to prove it.

Comment: Would you do that with induction?

Comment: No, I'd use a direct manipulation. $n\cdot(7n + 11) < 7(7n^2+3) \iff \dotsc$, and note $\lvert (-1)^n7n+11\rvert \leqslant 7n + 11$.

Comment: You're on the right track except for two things.  First, as Daniel points out above, intuition is not a proof.  Second, you can't disregard the absolute value in your analysis.  So there are two things that remain to be proved:  $\frac{7(-1)^n+11}{7(7n^2+3)}< \frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{7(-1)^n+11}{7(7n^2+3)}> -\frac{1}{n}$.  Both cases should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
you can choose n in better way
you can use sup of a(n) or a bit more to find n>N ,which satisfy that relation